# Pyarrow Table.from_pandas changing supplied schema

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I have an incrementally populated partitioned parquet table being constructed using Python (3.6)/Pandas (0.23.4). After about 50 partitions, I have a pandas data frame that contains columns that are entirely NaNs. I am taking the schema from the first partition discovered and assigning it to the pyarrow Table:

```
sschema = _retrieve_schema(root_path) if isinstance(fs, pa.LocalFileSystem) else None

for keys, subgroup in data_df.groupby(partition_keys):
    if not isinstance(keys, tuple):
        keys = (keys,)
    subdir = "/".join(
        ["{colname}={value}".format(colname=name, value=val)
         for name, val in zip(partition_cols, keys)])
    subtable = Table.from_pandas(subgroup, schema=sschema, preserve_index=preserve_index, nthreads=nthreads)
```

The schema on the resulting table does not match the schema supplied to the from_pandas method. The columns with NaNs have the correct pandas_type of float64. However, the numpy type has been changed from float64 to object. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

** Edit **
I tried the experimental replace_schema_metadata method of the Table object and it seems to fix the problem when running in a local IPython console on Windows. When I move to a Jupyter notebook on Linux (same python/pandas versions) it still has the same issue, using the same data (i.e. scp'ed the parquet files to the host running the notebook).

It looks like there is a change between pyarrow 0.9.0 and 0.10.0 that prevents a partition's schema with an all NaN column from being read correctly causing failure in the pandas.read_parquet

Comment: Can you please report bugs or other problems on the Arrow issue tracker? http://issues.apache.org/jira, or if you are not sure you can e-mail the mailing list dev@arrow.apache.org